# How do I enable username for Redis 6+

Tags: redis, bitnami, redis-cluster

I am trying to upgrade Redis into 6+ which supports ACLs.
Well,I am planning to use Bitnami for helm deployments and bring up the redis-clusters.

But the problem is how can I set up "username" in the configurations using helm.
The Bitnami does not have the field username under https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/redis-cluster/README.md#cluster-management-parameters

Eventually I tried to test this using a docker-compose file but since my Redis instances were running on docker container and my application was not, I was not able to communicate to Redis instances which were created.

Hence, I thought let me try using helm.